# webcam LED, hardware or software?

Tags: hardware, webcam

To my knowledge most webcams are equipped with a LED which will turn ON if the webcam is being used.

I was wondering if a software can avoid the LED behing activated or if it's built-in electronic.

In other terms : If my webcam LED is off does it means 100% nobody is using it ? Remote or local.

Comment: it's called standards, and most companies are supposed to follow them. I'm not interested about an answer on a specific webcam model, I would like to have an answer from someone who understand how a webcam is electronicaly built, thank you.

Comment: So how is that programming related? My webcam I can disable the LED via the web interface. Without a model how do you know what "standard": is applied?

Comment: Oh you can programmatically disable the LED on your webcam ?

Comment: @bobdylan This has nothing to do with standards.

Comment: I was wondering maybe constructors put the LED on the same circuit that turn the webcam ON. So if electricity go to the webcam the light will automatically turn ON too, and no program can change that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If my webcam LED is off does it means 100% nobody is using it ?

No. It does not.
For example I have 2 brands of webcam (I think one is a copy of the other) and I can disable the LED through the camera's built in web API.